# Need some help making a checklist module in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, checkbox

So I need to make a checklist for a web app where an administrator can edit a checklist for a user. The administrator can check those when a certain condition is met and also write a comment about it if necessary.

I set up 3 tables:

- A user table which stores all the user information like name, birthplace and so on. Primary key is `user_idnr`
- Then I have a table called `CHECKLIST_properties`. It stores all the different items of the checkbox. It has the following columns:

  property_idnr | type | description
- Finally, I have a table called `CHECKLIST_user_property`. It is used to link a property to a user, when a row is created, it is checked. It has the following columns:

  link_idnr | user_idnr | property_idnr | comments

I am having trouble planning out how to save the checked boxes in the database. You need to determine when a row needs to be added or removed from the table. Can anyone give me some tips on how to set this up properly?

Comment: Are checklist properties reusable for different users ? Like do you provide current properties and then if the administrator needs to add another one they can ? So, for example, an administrator is making the list for a user, he picks some already existing properties for the checklist, then he wants to add one more that doesn't exists, so he creates it.

Comment: To add a new property wouldn't you just check if one exists with the same description and type, if it doesn't then create it.

Comment: It's mostly a generic checklist that is the same for every user. In the future I might add something that the administrator can add new questions, but that will be global for all users, I think.

Comment: In that case you're not really adding or remove rows from the checklist properties table right ? You're just adding a property_idnr for each property you want to show up on the users checklist.

Comment: I guess i don't get where you're stuck at.

Comment: Haha, sorry I am a little bit vague in this.. xP But I think I'm mostly stuck at the query, like how do I save a changed state (checked or unchecked) for an existing row and that kind of stuff..

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of options:

1. remove all the rows and add the currently selected ones back in.  This can have unintended side-effects (new auto incrementing numbers, etc).
2. add a column that is used to track the status of the rows.  Use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to add rows to the table and/or update existing rows.  The new/updated rows would have a different value in the new column (like a timestamp).  Then delete all the rows with an older value (as they weren't added/updated, they're not needed).